# How to use window function in Redshift?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, window-functions

I have 2 tables:
| Product |
|:----: |
| product_id  |
| source_id|

| Source |
| --- |
| source_id |
| priority |

sometimes there are cases when 1 product_id can contain few sources and my task is to select data with min priority from for example
| product_id  | source_id| priority|
|:----: |:------:| :-----:|
| 10| 2| 9|
| 10| 4| 2|
| 20| 2| 9|
| 20| 4| 2|
| 30| 2| 9|
| 30| 4| 2|

correct result should be like:
| product_id  | source_id| priority|
|:----: |:------:| :-----:|
| 10| 4| 2|
| 20| 4| 2|
| 30| 4| 2|

I am using query:

```
SELECT p.product_id, p.source_id, s.priority FROM Product p
INNER JOIN Source s on s.source_id = p.source_id
WHERE s.priority = (SELECT Min(s1.priority) OVER (PARTITION BY p.product_id) FROM Source s1)
```

but it returns error **"this type of correlated subquery pattern is not supported yet"** so as i understand i can't use such variant in Redshift, how should it be solved, are there any other ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to unroll the where clause into the second data source and the easiest flag for min priority is to use the ROW_NUMBER() window function.  You're asking Redshift to rerun the window function for each JOIN ON test which creates a lot of inefficiencies in clustered database.  Try the following (untested):

```
SELECT p.product_id, p.source_id, s.priority 
FROM Product p
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.product_id, order by s1.priority) as row_num,
        source_id,
        priority
    FROM Source) s 
on s.source_id = p.source_id
WHERE row_num = 1
```

Now the window function only runs once.  You can also move the subquery to a CTE if that improve readability for your full case.

Answer (score 0):

Already found best solution for that case:

```
SELECT
  p.product_id
, p.source_id
, s.priority
, Min(s.priority) OVER (PARTITION BY p.product_id) as min_priority
FROM Product p
    INNER JOIN Source s
            ON s.source_id = p.source_id
WHERE s.priority = p.min_priority
```